# i want to split the integer into individual elements and add the elements

Tags: python, loops, oop, if-statement

i made a code to split an integer and add them individually but in some scenario the sum is wrong
**for example the output expected for 555 is 15 but it shows 16**

```
def find_sum_of_digits(number):
    sum_of_digits=0
    sum=0
    var=0
    #Write your logic here
    while number>0:
        var = number%10
        
        sum += var
        number = number/10
        sum_of_digits=sum
        
    return int(sum_of_digits)

#Provide different values for number and test your program
sum_of_digits=find_sum_of_digits(123)
print("Sum of digits:",sum_of_digits)
```

The output i want is to add 123 to display 6 and as vice versa to other integer values

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Is there a reason you have both `sum` and `sum_of_digits`? These seem to be redudant and you only need one of them.

Comment: I assume you did `int(sum_of_digits)` because you saw decimal numbers printed out. The fact that you see decimals is a clue that there is something wrong with your algorithm that should be dealing with integers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
number = int(input("Enter the Number: "))

sum_of_digits = 0
while number > 0: 

    digit = number % 10
    sum_of_digits = sum_of_digits + digit
    
    number = number // 10
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple `print` to trace your values would show the problem:

```
number = number/10
```

You need *integer* division:

```
number = number//10
```

Your code computes the infinite sum, and then has to divide by 10 until the remaining number dwindles to 0 for the internal representation.

An easier way to do this is to take the original string input and convert each character of the string to a single-digit integer.  Add those integers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be:

```py
def find_sum_of_digits(number):
  return sum([int(n) for n in str(number)])
```

Comment: Yes, I know, OP asked to help debug their implementation. Which has already been done perfectly by Prune.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that uses the example provided in your original question as a starting point.

```py
def find_sum_of_digits(number):
    result = 0 # Variable to store result
    while number > 0:
        digit = number % 10 # Current digit is remainder from number / 10
        result += digit # Add digit to result and assign value to result variable
        number //= 10 # Number is number // 10 to shift left to next digit, disregarding fractional part of quotient
    return result
```

Note the use of the [floor division operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html)(`//`) instead of the standard division operator (`/`) when dividing `number` by 10 to shift left to the next digit. It is this change that will stop you from getting erroneous `return` values (such as `16` instead of `15` when `number = 555`).

Python floor division returns an `int` representing the truncated division of two numbers; instead of a `float` (as standard division does in Python), this is required for your purposes as you are only concerned with the `int` digits of `number` and not any fractional portions that may arise from standard division - these are being summed before you cast back to `int` in your original example.

Here is another valid solution that results in the desired output. This time we are returning the result of the `sum` function which is given a list comprehension of `int` instances representing each digit of `number`.

```py
def find_sum_of_digits(number):
   return sum([int(d) for d in str(number)])
```

In this case, the `int` representing each digit of `number` is found by first casting `number` to a `str`, then iterating across each `char` of the `number` `str`, casting each back to an `int`.